# Firebase - User still exist after delete

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

When I deleted the user from the Realtime Database by clicking the bin next to it, the user disappears, its okay, but I can still log in by his email and password, and when the login is successful, the UUID of this user reappears when I write some values to subtables in the database, but without his values defined while registering.

I thought that it should be fine after 1 hour and I could have still registered him as a new user, but I can't. I deleted him 2 days ago. What is wrong, how i can delete a user permanently - not by blocking him?

Part of my main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //textview,buttons,progress bars, etc...
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
        forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
...
    //Onclicks, textview value correctness etc...

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    if(user.isEmailVerified()){
                        // redirect to user profile
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileDashboard.class));
                    }else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        user.sendEmailVerification();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Check your email to verify your account!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to login! Please check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Realtime Database` is not the same as `Authentication`.

Deleting the user in Authentication will do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the mentioned comment above, deleting from Database is not same as authentication.

So to do this you may use the firebase admin SDK.
You can see an example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users.

So basically what you can do is to delete the user from the DB, then from the Firebase Auth to avoid having that kind of issues; example:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.delete()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: By the UI, as the previous comment mentioned. Or a call to the API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-delete-account

Answer (score 1):

While @Dabbel solution indicates removing the user from the Console, it will indeed solve the problem, but please note that this operation might not be feasible in the case of a large number of users.

So the best option that you have is to remove the user from the Firebase Auth programmatically by calling [FirebaseUser#delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#delete()) which:

> Deletes the user record from your Firebase project's database.